# Factoring out noise in an algorithm

Tags: java, math, noise

I essentially have a bunch of data objects which map timestamps in milliseconds to float values. I'm looking to essentially find the peak/max of the data in a given range. I've been essentially using something like this:

```
float previousValue = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    MyData value = data.get(i);
    if (value.getData() < previousValue) {
        // found the peak!
        break;
    } else {
        previousValue = value.getData();
    }
}
```

The only problem with this algorithm is that it doesn't account for noise. Essentially, I could have values like this:

```
[0.1025, 0.3000, 0.3025, 0.3500, 0.3475, 0.3525, 0.1025]
```

The actual peak is at 0.3525, but my algorithm above would see it as 0.3500, as it comes first. Due to the nature of my calculations, I can't just do `max()` on the array and find out the largest value, I need to find the largest value that comes first before it falls.

How can I find the top of my peak, while accounting for some variance in noise?

Comment: how do you define the peak? 
the value after .3500 and the value after .3525 falls. What's the difference?

Comment: Separate the concerns: first, use sliding window and average the data — that'll eliminate the noise. After that, you can easily find peaks with your or any other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. filtering out the noise;
2. finding the peak.

It seems like you already have a solution for 2, and need to solve 1.

To filter out the noise, you need some kind of [low-pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter). A [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) is one such filter. For example, [exponential moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) is very easy to implement and should work well.

In summary: put your series through the filter, and then apply the peak finding algorithm.

Comment: So a low-pass filter will get rid of jumpy values and bring me back much more linear results? How can I write said filter? I'm pretty clueless when it comes to math.

Answer (score 0):

an easier method to find a single peak (or the highest value) in an array (any numeric array: int, double) is to loop through the array and set a  variable to the highest value...

Example: (all examples use a float array called "data")

```
float highest = 0; //use a number equal to or below the lowest possible value
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if (data[i] > highest){
        highest = data[i];
    }
}
```

to find multiple peaks in noisy data filtering some of the noise out I used this method:

```
boolean[] isPeak = new boolean[20]; // I am looking for 20 highest peaks
float[] filter = new float[9]; // the range to which I want to define a peak is 9
float[] peaks = new float[20]; // again the 20 peaks I want to find
float lowpeak = 100; // use a value higher than the highest possible value
// first we start the filter cycling through the data
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for (int a = filter.length-1; a > 0; a--){
        filter[a] = filter[a-1];
    }
    filter[0] = data[1]
    // now we check to see if the filter detects a peak
    if (filter[4]>filter[0] && filter[4]>filter[1] && filter[4]>filter[2] &&
            filter[4]>filter[3] && filter[4]>filter[5] && filter[4]>filter[6] &&
            filter[4]>filter[7] && filter[4]>filter[8]){
        // now we find the lowest peak
        for (int x = 0; x < peaks.lengt-1; x++){
            if (peaks[x] < lowpeak){
                lowpeak = peaks[x];
            }
        }
        // now we check to see if the peak is above the lowest peak 
        for (int x = 0; x < peaks.length; x++){
            if (peaks[x] > lowpeak && peaks[x] != peaks[x+1]){
                for (int y = peaks.length-1; y > 0 && !isPeak[y]; y--){
                peaks[y] = peaks[y-1];
                }
                peaks[0] = filter[4];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this may not be the most efficient way to do this but it gets the job done!